# How to change a section name in dynamics crm 2013

Tags: javascript, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I want to change a section name if my checkbox is checked their is my code 
I was trying to use a loop but I still had the same error !! 

 and I got this Error Message 

`Champ :cac_is_demande_mere Événement onchange 
Erreur :Unable to get property 'controls' of undefined or null reference`

```js
function Demande_Type()
{
    if (Xrm.Page.getAttribute("cac_is_demande_mere").getValue())
    {
        Xrm.Page.getControl("parentcaseid").setLabel("new Field");

        Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get("general").sections.get("ChildCasesGrid").controls.setLabel("new Field");

    /* var ctrlName = Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get();   
        for(var i in ctrlName) {    
             var ctrl = ctrlName[i];    
             var ctrlSection = ctrl.getParent().getName();  
             if (ctrlSection == "ChildCasesGrid") { 
                   ctrl.setLabel("new Field");  
            }   
        }   */


    }
    else 
    {
        Xrm.Page.getControl("parentcaseid").setLabel("Demande Parente");
        Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get("general").sections.get("ChildCasesGrid").controls.setLabel("Demandes Filles");
    /* var ctrlName = Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get();   
        for(var i in ctrlName) {    
             var ctrl = ctrlName[i];    
             var ctrlSection = ctrl.getParent().getName();  
             if (ctrlSection == "ChildCasesGrid") { 
                   ctrl.setLabel("Demandes Filles");    
            }   
        }*/
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code I can suggest to recheck id of a section. Is it really ChildCasesGrid? Could you please provide a screenshot of section settings form?

Based on provided screenshot you use id of a grid and not of a section on which it is put. So solution - find Id of a section and put it to your code.

Answer (score 0):

Since the only `.controls` you're attempting follows this line

```
Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get("general").sections.get("ChildCasesGrid")
```

then it means that `.get("ChildCasesGrid")` result is null or undefined.

This means that you don't have any section named `ChildCasesGrid` inside the tab named `general`: either one of the names is wrong (watch out, they are case-sensitive).

Comment: I don' know if is case-senstive but you can see the picture in the bottom

Answer (score 0):

[image: screenshot of section settings form]

@andrii butenko that's the  name of my section

Comment: As far as I can see you provided a screenshot of Grid and not of the section. That's why your code fails.

Comment: I'm so sorry I want to change the name of this Grid ("DEMANDE FILLES") to ("Demande")

Comment: So for what you wanted to change the label - for a grid or for a section?

Answer (score 0):

You actually want to do `Xrm.Page.getControl("ChildCasesGrid").setLabel("new label")` to set the label of a Sub-Grid